# Print javascript alert with the value available in request object

Tags: java, javascript, request

I am trying to alert a value which is available in request object, following is my code:

```
<%
    String isValidTransaction="";
     if (request.getAttribute("isValidTransaction") != null)
     {
       isValidTransaction =  request.getAttribute("isValidTransaction").toString();
%>
<script>
  var transactionAlert = "<%=isValidTransaction%>";
  if(transactionAlert.length == 0)
  {
   alert(transactionAlert);
  }
</script>
<span class="formError" id="isValidTransaction">
  <h1><%=request.getAttribute("isValidTransaction").toString()%></h1>
</span> 
<%}%>
```

but the alert message is printed and the whatever is printed in `<h1><%=request.getAttribute("isValidTransaction").toString()%></h1>` is getting printed.

so, how to alert a value using javascript which is available in request object?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure: `if(transactionAlert.length == 0) alert(transactionAlert);` ? It could only alert empty box.

Comment: If you are using .net, you can convert data by Json.Encode(), then javascript can read it, such as: `<script> var transactionAlert = <%=Json.Encode(myData)%>; ... `

Comment: I am sorry the problem is `if(transactionAlert.length == 0)` it is supposed to be `if(transactionAlert.length != 0)` it works now. thanks to @Zac

Answer (score 0):

You should use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` function. Because `alert()` just return object.toString().